# How is strpos() in PHP counting?

Tags: php, strpos

I see some strange results with strpos() function...

```
echo strpos("naše republika", "a"); // 1
echo strpos("naše republika", "š"); // 2
echo strpos("naše republika", "e"); // 4 ???
```

Can someone explain it to me? Thanks. (php 5.6.30)

Comment: It counts in bytes, not characters (by default).... unless you've tweaked the `mbstring.func_overload` setting in your php.ini (not recommended)

Comment: Use `mb_strpos`.

Comment: Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php and [this user contributed note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#118905).

Comment: Thanks @brevis - 'mb_strpos()' is the function I was looking for...

Comment: Here š occupy 2 positions so, count +2 for that character. so, n=0, a=1, š=2,3 & e=4